# What's the url to call AdWords and BigQuery from ads script with a service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-ads-api, service-accounts, google-ads-script

I want to modify these API calls to use a GCP service account instead of my identity.

```
var report = AdsApp.search(searchQuery);
  
var table = BigQuery.Tables.insert(table, projectId, dataSetId);

BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID);
```

I read this [article](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/natural-language) but wasn't sure how to find the url for `AdsApp` and `BigQuery`.

I searched this [post](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call#python_2), but still haven't been sure.

Hi,

I want to write an Ads-script to call GoogleAds url nad BQ url using a service account.

I saw this code.
Are my urls to the GAds and BQ api correct?

Thanks!

=====================

```
  // Natural Language API Sentiment URL
  var url =
      'https://language.googleapis.com/v1beta1/documents:analyzeEntities';

  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify(body)
  };
  var response = authUrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(result);
  if (result.entities) {
    // return a list of identified entities
    return result.entities;
  }
  throw Error('No entities response returned');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the urls:

```
  var url =...;
  
  
  //https://adwords.google.com/cm/CampaignMgmt?authuser=1&__u=%param_one%&__c=%param_two%#c.%param_three%.create&app=cm
  //https://bigquery.googleapis.com
  //https://adwords.google.com/cm/CampaignMgmt?
  
  
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify(body)
  };
  var response = authUrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(result);
  if (result.entities) {
    // return a list of identified entities
    return result.entities;
  }
  throw Error('No entities response returned');
}
```